# How to define relationship with pivot table laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two table one is pivot table and other is normal table that is

**user_pharmacies**

```
user_pharmacies_id  | user_id | pharmacy_id
```

**user_price**

```
price_id | product_id | user_pharmacies_id | price
```

you can see primary key of pivot table is foreign key in user_price table. My question is how to define the relation between these two table i don't want to make model of pivot table

Comment: Please provide more details on your db structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure is entirely wrong. Please read the laravel documentation first on how to properly setup relationships by using a pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Which one is your pivot table? I do not think any of above is pivot table. 
For the above tables you have to use two models, but if you have any real pivot table then you do not need to create model for that pivot table in laravel. You can use eloquent relationship to fetch the data from pivot table.

For example, you have following three tables : `users` , `roles` and `user_roles` then you only need to create models for `users` and `roles` table. You can use [eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) to fetch data from pivot table.